# java tags and labels (other than inside of loops)

Tags: java, tags, label

Is there any way in java so that i can go forwards and backwards in the code?
I want to create some code where the user can decide between various options, can I use labels or do i have to use a switch?

i want to code something like this:

```
public static void main(String[]args){

START:
   System.out.println("What do you whish to do?");
   System.out.println("X");
   System.out.println("Y");
   System.out.println("Z");

      if(kbd.nextLine().equals("X")){goto x;}
      if(kbd.nextLine().equals("Y")){goto y;}
      if(kbd.nextLine().equals("Z")){goto z;}

X: //CODE FOR ACTION X// 
goto START;
Y: //CODE FOR ACTION Y// 
goto START;
Z: //CODE FOR ACTION Z// 
goto START;
}
```

Is it there any way so that i can do this on java without using a switch?

Comment: **PLEASE** do not try to create a `goto`. It's an *unimplemented* **reserved** word for a reason. Based on what you have posted, use a ***loop***.

Comment: There are few solutions to your problem but they all depend on what you *really* want to achieve. You can use combination of loops, methods, or you could simply put your code directly in `if` block.

Comment: Use different methods.

Comment: I recommend reading through this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code would not work anyway. If the user entered "Y", the first if would not execute the GOTO, and the program would the n be waiting for an input at the next line.

it should rather be something like this (you could use either if's or switch):

```
String exitCode = "q";
String ans = "";
while(!ans.equals(exitCode) {
   System.out.println("What do you wish to do?");
   System.out.println("X");
   System.out.println("Y");
   System.out.println("Z");
   String ans = kbd.nextLine();
   if ( ans.equals("X") {
     // code for X action
   } else if ( ans.equals("Y" ) {
      // code for Y action
   } else if ( ... ) {
     // etc
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i wanted to use it so the code would be more clean, but i guess i'll have to do it the rough way